# Sharing Windows Authentication between multiple applications

Tags: windows, active-directory, iis

I have two applications with Windows Authentication turned on. The second application is called in an iframe inside the first application.
In the intranet, it is working fine as it is taking currently logged in user from the computer and not prompting for credentials. But from outside network, it is prompting for credentials for both the applications.

[Scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEcFZ.jpg)

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: What's the expected behavior ? Don't prompt for credentials at all? Prompt only once ? by "outside network" you mean not domain joined computers?

Comment: @Swisstone It should ask only once for the main site. Outside network is exactly not domain joined systems which include mobiles

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is expected, it works when you are in your intranet network/domain because the browser (Internet Explorer for example) can use the Integrated Windows Authentication (given that your domain is in the Windows' Intranet security zone)

If you use a non-domain joined device, the browser "sees" two completely different domains and has no idea that they are related each other.

*Maybe*, if you bring the iframe on the same domain that the parent frame you will see only one authentication request.